# what function set "program_invocation_name" ? and when?

Tags: assembly, x86, binary, executable, elf

Here is a bit of information I got about `program_invocation_name`:

- This value contains the name that was used to invoke the calling program.
- This value is automatically initialized.
- This value is global variable.
  (*So at the first sight, I thought it was in `<.bss>` or `<.data>`.

  But it was in `stack` memory region. That's weird...*)

Here is debugger view of `program_invocation_name`:

```
pwndbg> x/s program_invocation_name
0xbffff302: "/tmp/my_program"
```

***Problem)***

I followed the execution flow from the start of program to end, but I could not found the ***very moment*** that `program_invocation_name` is set.

***Question)***

***Q1***. Who(what function) set this value? (`loader` sets this value..?)
***Q2***. How program knows recognize it as `global variable`, although this value is located in the `stack`?
***Q3***. Sometimes, some binary runs without this value. In this case, It is problem of `loader`?

Comment: I think it's set by CRT code.  Set a breakpoint at `_start` and set a watchpoint on that variable to see what sets it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Who(what function) set this value? (loader sets this value..?)

You can answer this by setting a watchpoint on it:

```
(gdb) start

Temporary breakpoint 1, main () at t.c:5
5     return 0;
(gdb) info var program_invocation_name
All variables matching regular expression "program_invocation_name":

Non-debugging symbols:
0x00007ffff7dd43b8  program_invocation_name
0x00007ffff7dd43b8  program_invocation_name
(gdb) watch *(char **)0x00007ffff7dd43b8
Hardware watchpoint 2: *(char **)0x00007ffff7dd43b8
(gdb) run
Starting program: /tmp/a.out
Hardware watchpoint 2: *(char **)0x00007ffff7dd43b8

Old value = <unreadable>
New value = 0x7ffff7b9b7a5 ""
0x00007ffff7de4c02 in _dl_relocate_object () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
(gdb) c
Continuing.
Hardware watchpoint 2: *(char **)0x00007ffff7dd43b8

Old value = 0x7ffff7b9b7a5 ""
New value = 0x7fffffffdfa7 "/tmp/a.out"
0x00007ffff7b22963 in __init_misc () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff7b22963 in __init_misc () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007ffff7a5a134 in _init () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#2  0x00007ffff7de886a in call_init.part () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#3  0x00007ffff7de89bb in _dl_init () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#4  0x00007ffff7dd9c5a in _dl_start_user () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#5  0x0000000000000001 in ?? ()
#6  0x00007fffffffdfa7 in ?? ()
```

> ZQ2. How program knows recognize it as global variable, although this value is located in the stack?

The variable *is* a global variable in the `.data` section:

```
(gdb) info sym 0x00007ffff7dd43b8
program_invocation_name in section .data of /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
```

It's a pointer, that points into the stack (it points into stack area where the kernel passes `argv[]` to the process).

> Q3. Sometimes, some binary runs without this value. In this case, It is problem of loader?

The binary can not run *without* this variable. But the variable may point to empty string (if e.g. the parent process did not use the usual calling convention and instead did something like `execl("/tmp/a.out", (char*)NULL)`).

Also, the program can "wipe" its own stack (e.g. due to stack overflow, or intentionally to hide from `ps` (many rootkits do that)), and then `program_invocation_name` will continue to point to the stack location where program name used to be, but no longer is.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was the answer I was looking for