# How program find global variable inside stack?

Tags: assembly, x86, binary, stack, global-variables

As far as I know, when I declare global variable `int my_var;`,
It's at ***fixed address*** in `<bss>`(uninitialized global data) or `<.rodata>`(initialize global data) section.

ex)

```
int my_var;          // <= It is at <.bss> section
int my_var = 0x1337; // <= It is at <.rodata> section
```

So, program can find those *static* values using ***fixed address.***

***Problem***: However, I heard about global variable located in `<stack>`.

C runtime startup initialize global variable: `__environ`, `program_invocation_name`
And They are located in `<stack>`.... which means its address is not fixed.

***Question***. How program can finds global variable inside `stack` (non-fixed region) ?

Comment: As you've found, global variables are not stored on the stack. If they were, the first question would be: _which_ stack, as each thread has its own dedicated stack allocated to it.

Comment: Why two different questions for the same topic? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52275427/what-function-set-program-invocation-name-and-when

Comment: `int my_var = 0x1337;` can't go in `.rodata` unless it's `const`, that would make `my_var++` segfault.  It will actually go in `.data`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

__environ, etc... are not located within the stack; they are normal global variables which are pointers (that is, a variable whose value is an address) to locations within the stack.   The fact that the initial program environment, arguments, etc... are in the stack is an implementation detail.  They could just as easily be allocated in the heap, or in some other area to suit the runtime.

The only thing that is important is that the runtime startup and operating system agree on where to find them.

[ responding to comment ]
The program below should illustrate:

```
#include <stdio.h>
extern char **environ;

int main() {
 int x;
 printf("&envrion  = %p\n", &environ);
 printf("environ   = %p\n", environ);
 printf("*environ  = %p [%s]\n", *environ, *environ);
 printf("&x        = %p\n", &x);
 return 0;
}
```

on my system, when run (cc -static x.c; ./a.out), generates:

```
&envrion  = 0x6bbda8
environ   = 0x7ffdd6edb3e8
*environ  = 0x7ffdd6edb9a2 [CLUTTER_IM_MODULE=xim]
&x        = 0x7ffdd6edb2a4
```

Notice how &environ is at a much different address than environ, *environ and &x.  That is because the latter are within the stack, while environ itself is not.

Comment: You mean.. "program has global variable `X` that holds the address of `__environ` in stack, and OS can find `__environ` using global variable `X`". Am I understand correctly?

Comment: Thank you for your detailed and considerable reply ! :D

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide an example or reference to a book indicating a global variable stored on the stack?

The point of the stack is to allocate memory according to the scope of the (temporal) variables, so it doesn't make sense to use the stack for an "always-alive" variable (as you said, there are another sections for that purpose).

Regarding your example (`int my_var = 0x1337;`), an initialised variable may not be allocated on a read-only section, because it doesn't mean that it won't be modified at some moment (besides of compiler's decisions).

> Question. How program can finds global variable inside stack (non-fixed region) ?

The stack is a LIFO queue, in which a pointer indicates the lastest position, and each temporal variable gets an address (when it is created, within stack boundaries) that indicates its location, until it is destroyed (out of scope) and the stack pointer is updated. But environment variables are not stored on the stack, they are above it: https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/03/linux-processes-memory-layout/

Comment: Yeah. You can easily find `global variable in stack` example, using debbuger. Just attach debugger any simple program, and type `gdb> x/s program_invocation_name`. This is command for print `program_invocation_name`, which is global variable automatically initialized. Then, you'll find this value is located at stack memory region, even though It's a global variable.

Comment: @최지원: It's probably a *pointer to* stack memory, where the string pointed to by `argv[0]` is stored by the kernel before process startup.  The pointer *value* itself is stored in `.bss`, which you could see by looking at `&program_invocation_name`.  Oh, mevets already posted this as an answer.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thank you for your answer, Using your advice, I could found variable `&program_invocation_name`  in `mybinary`'s `.bss`!    However, in some binary,  `&program_invocation_name` is in the `.data` of `libc`, not `.bss` of `mybinary`. Do you know why is it? Is it because of ... maybe... compiler version issue or something like that?

Comment: @최지원: probably depends how you declare it in your C source, whether you override the library's symbol or not.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thank you for giving me a good answer every time. :)